# Using Visual Studio 2015, How to downgrade a WCF project's target framework from .NET 4.5.2 to 4.0?

Tags: wcf, target-framework

While I see many posts on how to downgrade other project types like MVC, etc. I can't find how to downgrade a WCF project from 4.5.2 to 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the target frame work on the application page of the project?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately my WCF project is built as a website and does not have this option. I believe my only answer is to rebuild my application with the 4.0 framework.

Comment: That sounds like the best option.

Just create a new WCF project and add the files from the website into your new solution.